# session tracking but login page with current user id using jsp and servlet

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

After logout the Page,the page are redirect into login page with the login user id...and password has been cleared.the program are implemented in jsp with servlet and also kill session

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: and explain in detail your problem

Comment: i set the session attribute in login controller page..like HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);session.setAttribute("userID",bean.getUserName());After kill the session..i get the userid in my login page userID text field

Answer (score 0):

use this code for the logout operation once if u click logout button that action will go to specific servlet and forward to login page. if this help you can use this.

```
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Login.html");
    }

}
```